how to change the size of my 3D model in Xcode project
I'm beginner in IOS developing so I made an AR app for iPhone in Xcode but i have a little problem: when I open my camera I can see me 3D model BUT I can't change the size and and place of my model. my 3D model placing in the middle and doesn't move. I want to fix my code ti have an opportunity to change size and place of my model by myself.
someone told me that I have to use "EntityGestures" but even with it it doesn't work
